# How to identify the user who may perform some deleting operation over a file?

Tags: linux, command-line, filesystems

There is a folder that maybe accessible to multiple users. If there is a file was deleted, is that possible to know which user delete this file and when? Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Yes. Use audit software. A popular implementation is `audit` or `auditd`. To help "prime the pump" on audit rules, one can acquire many audit-related rules for the software via the  [DISA STIG](https://stigviewer.com/stig/red_hat_enterprise_linux_6/).

Although the hyperlink points to a STIG (Security Technical Implementation Guide) for RHEL6 (RedHat Linux 6), it is nonetheless a good security *baseline* that will be mostly appropriate for your Linux system, perhaps with some interpolation to match your Linux.

The software is developed by RedHat but available for any Linux. There is 
[helpful documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security_Guide/chap-system_auditing.html) available.